# remote: Repository not found

Tags: git, github

I am a newbie with github and when I tried pushing my code to github it said remote repository not found.
The first time I tried it I was able to push my code but this time I was not able to. Could this be a problem with permission?
This is how my git looks like:

```
Me@ MINGW64 ~/JJJgin git@github.com:Alchemist21/MyWeb.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.

Me@ MINGW64 ~/Desktop/xxx2.0 (master)
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/xxx/MyWebsite.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/xxx/MyWebsite.git (push)

Me@ MINGW64 ~/Desktop/xxx2.0 (master)
$ git commit "Add files"
error: pathspec 'Add files' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Me@ MINGW64 ~/Desktop/xxx2.0 (master)
$ git commit -m "Add files"
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Me@ MINGW64 ~/Desktop/xxx2.0 (master)
$ git push origin master
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git/' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of you repo is `Alchemist21/MyWeb`, so make sure your URL is the right one (it is case sensitive)

```
cd xxxx2.0
git set-url origin https://github.com/Alchemist21/MyWeb.git
```

Then modify a file, make sure got config user.name and git config user.email are set.

```
git add .
git commit -m "new files"
git push -u origin master
```